# Raw opcode from xed decoded data structures?

Tags: intel-pin

I am new to Intel Pintools, and am trying to write a pintool that stops at a given instruction type and then looks for specific instructions following it in the section. I've got the xed decoding working, but I am stuck at the part where I get the actual hex opcode. How can I do that?

I would love to use INS_Opcode() -- but these are instructions that haven't been executed yet (and may never be), so they aren't INS objects. There's xed_operand_values_get_iclass(), but that returns an iclass enum, not the actual primary opcode. I see from the xed header files that there are some raw buffers associated with the various xed structures, but it is not at all clear to me how I can use that to get the information I need. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I missed it the first time I looked at the header files, but there's xed3_operand_get_nominal_opcode(), which does exactly what I need it to. Related: grep is a wonderful thing.